# Module ‘langchain.vectorstores.pinecone’ has no attribute ‘init’

Tags: langchain, pinecone

When I attempted to install ‘pinecone’ I received the error:

> “could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pinecone”

So instead, I installed pinecone-client

Here is my code:

```
from langchain.vectorstores import pinecone
pinecone.init(api_key=“API_KEY”, environment=“asia-northeast1-gcp”)
```

I receive the following error:

> File “C:\Users\Luke\PycharmProjects\Langchainv1\Langchain_Pinecone.py”, line 2, in
> pinecone.init(api_key=“API_KEY”, environment=“asia-northeast1-gcp”)
> AttributeError: module ‘langchain.vectorstores.pinecone’ has no attribute ‘init’

Does this error have anything to do with the fact that I was unable to install pinecone but installed pinecone-client? That doesn't appear to be the case using Pinecones documentation: https://docs.pinecone.io/docs/python-client

I appreciate any help. I have reinstalled pinecone-client and am a bit stumped.

I am attempting to embed text to pinecone to use for queries using Langchain. Unfortunately, I cannot even get to the point where pinecone is loading properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with the latest version of pinecone-client

Fixed it by running the following

```
!pip install -q --upgrade pinecone-client==2.2.4
import pinecone
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps to getting Pinecone set up with LangChain: (1) connect to Pinecone client with the `pinecone` module and authenticate, then (2) use the `Pinecone` interface that LangChain provides.

You already have done some of the steps, and @NickODell noted the right way to import the Pinecone client. This answer demonstrates a quick walkthrough of both steps in this process.

**Step 1: Initialize/Authenticate Pinecone client**

```
#!pip install pinecone-client
import pinecone 

pinecone.init(
    api_key=os.environ["PINECONE_API_KEY"], 
    environment=os.environ["PINECONE_ENV"]
)

pc_index_name = "put-your-pinecone-index-name-here"
pc_namespace = "if-you-are-using-a-namespace-put-it-here"

# note: these 2 lines are not strictly necessary, just testing client connection
pc_index = pinecone.Index(pc_index_name)
pc_index.describe_index_stats()
```

**Step 2: Create LangChain Pinecone interface**

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone

pc_interface = Pinecone.from_existing_index(
    pc_index_name, 
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(), 
    namespace=pc_namespace
)

from langchain.chains.qa_with_sources import load_qa_with_sources_chain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

# now you can do QA with your Pinecone DB or whatever else you want
my_qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain(
    combine_documents_chain=load_qa_with_sources_chain(...),
    retriever=pc_interface.as_retriever()
)
```

So `pinecone` (lowercase) is the Pinecone client module, made by Pinecone. And `Pinecone` (uppercase) is the LangChain interface to a Pinecone vectorstore, made by LangChain (which needs an authenticated `pinecone.init()` in order to function).

Comment: Thank both of you so much. That worked perfectly. I just got started in Python, and this has been my first roadblock. Nice to have such generous people on stackoverflow.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solution answered your question, please mark it accepted with the check button, that way others will know your post has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
from langchain.vectorstores import pinecone
```

The correct import here is `import pinecone`.

Answer (score 0):

`init()` method is no longer supported or available in the Pinecone package you are using. Instead you can use:

```
pc = Pinecone(api_key=YOUR_API_KEY)
index = pc.Index(YOUR_INDEX_NAME)
```